# Wxpython EVT_CHAR callback not getting called

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an OpenGL wxpython app that I'm trying to get working in Ubuntu. It was developed (by someone else) on Mac OSX, and works just fine there.

The last outstanding problem I have is that keyboard events aren't getting captured.

The code looks something like this:

```
class GLFrame(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(...):
         ...
         self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.mouseMotion)
         self.canvas.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.character)
         ...

def character(self, evt):
    print "EVT_CHAR"
    # do stuff

def mouseMotion(self, evt):
    print "EVT_MOTION"
    # do stuff
```

I've grepped the entire codebase for Bind calls, and nothing else is using EVT_CHAR, EVT_KET_DOWN or EVT_KEY_UP. I've also tried both EVT_KEY_DOWN and EVT_KEY_UP, and neither of them work.

I've also tried changing the bind calls from

```
self.canvas.Bind(...)
```

to

```
self.Bind(...)
```

This breaks EVT_MOTION, and the EVT_CHAR callback still doesn't get called.

Are there any calls that might capture keyboard events before they get to GLFrame? I'm new to wxpython, and while it mostly makes sense to me, I'm sure there are 'gotchas' that I am unaware of.

Comment: does the canvas have focus? also try using wx.ACCEPTS_CHARS style (I think thats it...)

Comment: It looks like the style is wx.WANTS_CHARS. Doesn't work though. Pretty sure the canvas has focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wxpython Google group, whether or not wx.Frame receives keyboard events is implementation-dependent. The Ubuntu implementation does not receive them.

From: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wxpython-users/dF2gf5KvFhE/M_-aRuG3aWUJ

> Whether wx.Frames are able to catch key events is not defined by wx and 
>   therefore implementation dependent.  The fact that it may work on some 
>   platforms is basically just a happy coincidence.  I'm not sure about the 
>   GLCanvas class, but I would expect it to be able to if it has the focus. 
>     You may want to double check where the focus is at by doing something 
>   like "print wx.Window.FindFocus()" from a timer or something.

Turns out, the GLCanvas can receive keyboard events just fine. For whatever reason, it wasn't getting focus. Calling

```
self.canvas.SetFocus()
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try binding to the frame rather than the canvas..

```
class GLFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.mouseMotion)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.character)


    def character(self, evt):
        print "EVT_CHAR"
        # do stuff

    def mouseMotion(self, evt):
        print "EVT_MOTION"

a = wx.App(redirect=False)
f = GLFrame(None,-1)
f.Show()
a.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I tried this (second half of my question). It didn't fix EVT_CHAR, and broke EVT_MOTION.

Comment: you copied this exact code? ... cause it works for me ... what wx version are you using? what python? (TBH Im on windows and that may be why it works for me...)

Comment: Interesting. I copied and pasted the code. EVT_MOTION works but EVT_CHAR is broken. I'm running Python 2.7.3 and python-wxgtk2.8.

Comment: Im Py2.6 but I doubt thats the problem .. probably OS?...does it work if you click the frame first to make sure it has focus?

Comment: Clicking the frame doesn't help. I might add a textfield somewhere, but that feels like such a hack...

Comment: try changeing the event to listen for `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN` ... maybe ?

Comment: No luck for any keyboard events (char, up down).